# Changing the window size\ hop size of KStream's sliding-windowed application

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, sliding-window

I have a KStream application that runs for a while and creates aggregations using the sliding window functionality (1-hour window with 10-minutes hop).

I wonder what will happen if I will change the hop size...

- Can I just deploy it with the window hop change and KStream will know how to handle it?
- Will it start the aggregation from the offset it currently points to? (then it means that I will have a partial picture for an hour or so - according to the window size)
- What will happen with the data in the changelog topic? will it stay there until the configured retention time will over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular case, you should be able to redeploy the application. The existing data should not be affected, and the application should resume where you left off. Of course, as you pointed out, you would miss some past windows entirely, if they may contain only partial data.

The data in the changelog topic should not be affected either and regular retention time applies.